# How to add or check data in more than one table by clicking one JButton

Tags: java, mysql

I have a database named **library** and it contains two tables named ***teacher*** and ***student***.
I have a JFrame named **Signup** and it contains various fields to signup.There is also a option to signup as "Teacher","Student" in a JComboBox.I can choose only one option and it will save in the selected database. means if i choice "Teacher" it will save in **teacher** table. I want to check Unique Username.But by clicking One ***JButton*** named **REGISTER NOW** How can I Check the Unique Username from the both table named **teacher** and **student** ?
Means I select ***signup as teacher*** so I must check unique username from table **teacher** and if I select ***signup as student*** so I must check unique username from table **student** and show me if the username already exists in the table by clicking the button to register.
My code is given below:

```
String id,name1,phn,email,dpt,wrk,uname,pas;

try {
    id = ID.getText();
    name1 = name.getText();
    phn = phone.getText();
    email = mail.getText();
    dpt = department.getText();
    wrk = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
    uname = username.getText();
    pas = pass.getText();
    
    
    pst = con.prepareStatement("select ID,Name,Phone,Email,Department,Work,Username,Password from student where Username = ?");
    pst.setString(1, uname);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    
    if(rs.next()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username already exists");
        username.setText("");
        pass.setText("");
    }
    
    else {
        if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Teacher")) {
            pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into teacher(ID,Name,Phone,Email,Department,Work,Username,Password)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            
            pst.setString(1, id);
            pst.setString(2, name1);
            pst.setString(3, phn);
            pst.setString(4, email);
            pst.setString(5, dpt);
            pst.setString(6, wrk);
            pst.setString(7, uname);
            pst.setString(8, pas);
            
            pst.executeUpdate();
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Created Successfully");
            dispose();
            Start st = new Start();
            st.setVisible(true);
                    
            ID.setText("");
            name.setText("");
            phone.setText("");
            mail.setText("");
            department.setText("");
            comboBox.setSelectedItem("");
            username.setText("");
            pass.setText("");
            
            username.requestFocus();
        }
        else if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Student")) {
            pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into student(ID,Name,Phone,Email,Department,Work,Username,Password)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            
            pst.setString(1, id);
            pst.setString(2, name1);
            pst.setString(3, phn);
            pst.setString(4, email);
            pst.setString(5, dpt);
            pst.setString(6, wrk);
            pst.setString(7, uname);
            pst.setString(8, pas);
            
            pst.executeUpdate();
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Created Successfully");
            dispose();
            Start st = new Start();
            st.setVisible(true);
                    
            ID.setText("");
            name.setText("");
            phone.setText("");
            mail.setText("");
            department.setText("");
            comboBox.setSelectedItem("");
            username.setText("");
            pass.setText("");
            
            username.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}
catch(SQLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you register with the same username once as teacher and once at student?

Comment: No, I can check only one database to check unique username and I Used teacher table to check the unique username.but I want to check the both table's username but I don't know the process to check both table from one button clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for instance use [`UNION ALL`](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union_all.php) to check in the username in both tables

```
pst = con.prepareStatement("select id from student where Username = ? union all select id from teacher where Username = ?");
pst.setString(1, uname);
pst.setString(2, uname);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

If the username is unique for both tables (ie a username must only exist in one of the tables) you can break, if this query returns a record, like you currently do.

Comment: thanks.it works perfectly.can you tell me about UNION ALL? I mean can I use this method to check the databeases to update or delete or login from One JButton also?

Comment: @MK.Whridoy check the docs https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union_all.php